# Eclipse plugin vs Java 17

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, java-17

I'm working on updating a large old Java application to Java 17.
It was on Java 11.  Note that we build in Eclipse, and all the projects that are part of this application have Java 1.8 compatibility turned on.

Now that I've updated it all to Java 17 (and updated the truckload of .jar files we use to their latest versions as well), I'm getting a problem with a code generator plugin we wrote.

I was able to rebuild the plugin .jar and it seems to be valid.  The problem is that when it runs, it fails With this msg:

```
The method parse(File) from the type DataModelParser refers to the missing type ParserConfigurationException
```

Since the class definitely exists, I'm assuming it's running into the issue where Java doesn't like being able to find the class in 2 places.
using Ctrl-Shift-T, I find the class available from Java 17 (expected) and "C:\Users\JohnLuss.p2\pool\plugins\javax.xml_1.3.4.v201005080400.jar"

That jar is part of Eclipse - so why does Eclipse have jars that conflict with java 17?
HOW can I make this work?  Is there any way to exclude the Eclipse jar?

Comment: That is a very old plugin and hasn't been part of Eclipse since Eclipse 4.7. I don't get any issues using ParserConfigurationException in Eclipse 2022-09 (4.25)

Comment: That's odd, as this is a recent eclipse install.  Probably means one of the plugins I installed dragged that in?

Comment: The mentioned plugin is in a shared pool that is used by all installations done via the Eclipse Installer. The dependency to the plugin/bundle or package must be declared, otherwise it won't work. So please show how you have declared the dependency.